# CSS Change shape background color on every click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like said in the title. I have some trouble changing the shape background color "onclick". The colors are listed in array but it doesn't mean I just need random value from the array. I want to change the colors in the correct order as listed in array. Moreover I need a variable saying which one of the colors is currently selected.

If anyone has some better idea of making it - I'm willing to find out.

The code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zmtU4/262/)

```
for color in colors {
    function button_click() {
```

Probably even the wrong way of calling the function?

Comment: Forked your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/c90n52z5/2/. JS is event based so you need to change status (here color) when the event occur not before.

Answer (score 3):

From what I could understand, you want to change color of box on click and every time you click the next color from the array appears.

Here's a simple implementation of that:

```js
var colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow","purple"];
var i = 0;
var selectedColor;
    function button_click() {
        selectedColor = colors[i];
        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
        i++;
        if(i > colors.length)
            i = 0;
    }
```

```css
div#box
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="button_click();"></div>
```

i is the variable which increments every time you click the box which gets you the next color value from the array and when counter exceeds the number of colors it resets back to 0 (first color)

Answer (score 1):

Try my example below:

```js
var colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow","purple"];
var index = 0;
function button_click() {
   index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
   document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
}
```

```css
div#box
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="button_click();"></div>
```

Comment: I like a lot your solution, much smaller than mine, only the global `i` is not good

Answer (score 0):

I like all the answers, some is very nice, one or two lines of code.

This is a solution without using a global var `index`

This will always work, you need a circular list

EDIT: white as default and first color as discussed in the comments

```
var colors = ["white","red","blue","green","yellow","purple"];
function button_click() {
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    var background_color = box.style.backgroundColor;
    var i = colors.indexOf(background_color);
    if (i === colors.length-1) {
        i = -1;
    }
    box.style.backgroundColor = colors[i+1];
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmtU4/266/)

Comment: The method is good. But I also forgot to add color "white" which always needs to have index "0". Should it just be on the beggining of the array?

Comment: you just need to set in CSS a color that is not in the list, then it will always work

Comment: Any reason why to put it outside of the list? Actually I think it might be a better idea to just include it on the list because otherwise there would be a need for another statement like [if index is "0" then return the color to default (white)]. So I think it's just easier to keep the "white" on the list as "0" and get it on every time the index resets

Comment: if you put it in the list, as it is now the function will select also white as a color, if you want that, you can put it. The default color should be in the CSS.
EDIT: now may be I got it what you meant, fiddle updated

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow","purple"],
    currentColorIndex = 0;

function button_click() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor
        = colors[currentColorIndex];
    currentColorIndex = (currentColorIndex + 1) % colors.length;
}
```

You seem to have some experience with programming. I would suggest you picking up a book about javascript tho. Even a week of a read and getting used to the syntax will get you a long way.

---

### Edit

And this one if you care about the global namespace here:

```
Square = (function () {
    "use strict";

    var colors = ["white", "red","blue","green","yellow","purple"],
        currentColorIndex = 0,
        squareElement,
        initialize = function ()
        {
            squareElement = document.getElementById("box");
        },
        clickHandler = function () {                
            currentColorIndex = (currentColorIndex + 1) % colors.length;
            squareElement.style.backgroundColor = colors[currentColorIndex];
        };

    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        clickHandler: clickHandler
    };
}());

Square.initialize();
```

---

```
<div id="box" onclick="Square.clickHandler()"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uzno1fwy/

Comment: Thanks for a nice words. Very encouraging. I'm an experienced PHP and Python (dismissed) programmer. Now I'm picking up some new languages after a long while without coding anything big. So with your method I need to add "white" as the first element of an array to always have it's index as "0"?

Comment: You just add how much colors you want to the array. It will count them every time. So yes - you just add the starting color at the beginning and it works.

Comment: Actually I have some issues running your code on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7ob9wcy9/

Comment: all the solutions are good (except for the `index` outside of the function that is really bad), his code is good, just on the menu on the left select 'no wrap - in <head>' in place of 'onLoad'

Comment: Like said above - "in head" option in jsfiddle. As for the index - a matter of choice. Maybe it's used in many other functions. And for examples sake thats not even an issue worth a stumble.

Comment: well, if the same index it is shared in other functions it is even worse, never make dirty the global namespace. For an example it is fine, but why to do not make it better?

Comment: I can see you're being a little picky, when all it comes to is a snippet about coloring a square. All in all, your no-index solution is quite nifty if you ask me. Have a good day sir.